# Joining 3 sql tables with inner join and accessing null value

Tags: sql, oracle, join, null, sqlplus

I'm trying to access all the values in dateTo that have no specified date and only have Vancouver as the address but my code doesn't work. It displays 13 guest members when there should only be 1 that it gets.

This is the Schema

```
Hotel (hotelNo, hotelName, hotelAddress)
Room (roomNo, hotelNo, type, price)
Guest (guestNo, guestName, guestAddress)
Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo)
```

This is the code snippet for this particular function.

```
SELECT Hotel.hotelName, Hotel.hotelAddress, Room.roomNo, Booking.dateFrom, Booking.dateTo
FROM Hotel
INNER JOIN Room
ON Hotel.hotelNo = Room.hotelNo
INNER JOIN Booking
ON Room.hotelNo = Booking.hotelNo
WHERE Hotel.hotelAddress LIKE '%Vancouver%' 
AND Hotel.hotelAddress NOT LIKE '%North Vancouver%' 
AND Hotel.hotelAddress NOT LIKE '%West Vancouver%'
AND Booking.dateTo IS NULL;
```

Comment: your `booking` table references the `room` table by the `roomNo`. However, in your query you did not reference this column

Comment: as @cha is saying, your condition for Booking needs to include both the hotel and the room numbers ...